# TRACE logging level run infinitely on spring boot web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, startup, trace

I have a web app running with spring-boot

when I put the logging level:

```
logging.level.root=TRACE
```

From unknown reason it's run fast infinitely

Does someone know what could be the reason?

From my code inspection I find that it's starting when the spring launching on.

That's part of the starting log (SO don't let me add more rows ):

```
2023-08-08 15:07:12.926 TRACE 27396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'logging.register-shutdown-hook' in PropertySource 'servletConfigInitParams'
2023-08-08 15:07:12.928 TRACE 27396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'logging.register-shutdown-hook' in PropertySource 'servletContextInitParams'
2023-08-08 15:07:12.928 TRACE 27396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Searching for key 'logging.register-shutdown-hook' in PropertySource 'systemProperties'
2023-08-08 15:07:12.928 TRACE 27396 --- [  restartedMain]
```

Comment: What does *it's run fast infinitely* mean? Besides the fact that you have posted some normal tracing level log messages?

Comment: It's run fast and log more and more rows. 

The actual log contains dozens of rows. And not stopping run.

Comment: Expect *thousands* of rows. TRACE is **verbose** and you told it to do that *everywhere*.

Comment: But it is excessive, and without a break. thousands every second. It crashes the system eventually.

Comment: It should not "crashes the system eventually" unless you have extremely limited disk space, and even then you could add more disk space  or disable root level tracing. You should have realized that tracing everything isn't very productive already. You enable trace on small sections of code. Not everywhere.

Comment: So you are saying that it's expected behavior?

Comment: Based on what you've posted so far, yes.